# Update remaining amount on a debit card with MS Access / SQL according to card number

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to update the remaining amount of money on different debit cards. I have the 2 following tables : Cards and Transactions.
I would like my result to be:

```
 Number|Initial_Amount|Remaining_Amount         T_ID|T_Date|Credit_Card|Amount
----------------------------------------       ---------------------------------
    123|          1000|     820                    1| 05/02|        123| 100
    456|           200|     150                    2| 06/02|        456| 50
                                                   3| 06/02|        123| 80
```

I already wrote a query to sum the amount according to credit card:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sum(T2.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM Transactions AS T1 INNER JOIN Transactions AS T2 ON T1.Credit_Card = T2.Credit_Card
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Credit_Card, T1.Amount;
```

But I don't know where to go by now.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: How is the remaining amount calculated?  How do you know the initial amount?

Comment: I charge a certain amount on every card and i want to track how much of the card was used. In this example, the remaining amount of card number 123 should be 820 since there was 1000 and we used 100 in transaction 1 and 80 in transaction 3 (1000 - (100+80) = 820 ).

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this -- assuming you have a table that has the original amount:

```
select c.credit_card, c.original_amount,
       (c.original_amount - nz(sum(t.amount), 0)) as remaining
from cards as c left join
     transactions as t
     on t.credit_card = c.credit_card
group by c.credit_card, c.original_amount;
```

If you want to update `cards`, use a correlated subquery:

```
update cards
    set remaining_amount = (c.original_amount -
                            (select nz(sum(t.amount), 0)
                             from transactions as t
                             where t.cred_card = cards.credit_card
                            )
                           );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need except I need to update the remaining value into my Cards table. Can I do it with : UPDATE Credit_Cards SET Credit_Cards.Remaining_Amount = Your query ?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error: "Operation must use an updatable query"... I work on MS Access. I'm trying to find a solution that could fit to the problem but can't find it for the moment.. Would you have a suggestion to fix that ? @GordonLinoff

Comment: Do you know what can I do ?